# SQLite issue in where condition

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am facing up into a problem where I can't find any solution about a sqlite query.

These are my database tables:

```
public static final String TABLE_C = "columns";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "column_name";
public static final String PREFERENCE = "preference";
public static final String THRESH_MIN = "thresh_min";
public static final String THRESH_MAX = "thresh_max";
public static final String COD_DEVEUI = "cod_deveui";

public static final String CREATE_C = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_C + " ( " +
        _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, " +
        THRESH_MIN + " REAL, " +
        THRESH_MAX + " REAL, " +
        PREFERENCE + " INTEGER, " +
        COD_DEVEUI + " TEXT);";

public static final String TABLE_D = "devices";
public static final String TYPE = "type";
public static final String NAME = "name";
public static final String DEVEUI = "deveui";

public static final String CREATE_D = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_D + " ( " +
        _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        NAME + " TEXT, " +
        DEVEUI + " TEXT);";
```

Before this version, I did "deveui" FOREIGN KEY referenced with "cod_deveui".
Actually I want to update the column "preference" from the table "Columns" of a specific row, but when I try do this, it doesn't work. 
Using SQLite Manager from Firefox, I found the following issue:

[Simply SELECT from table "Devices". (OK)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlGqr.png)

[Put attention at the value "Numero1" from column "column_name" for example in this SELECT. (OK)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSB5A.png)

[When in my WHERE condition I put the value "Testo1", the query will return a correct result, but not with other values like "Numero1", "Numero2", "FloatP1". (ISSUE)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AT27C.png)

It seems like he can select or update just the first value from each "cod_deveui" group.
If I do WHERE conditions with _id, preference or cod_deveui works everthing, but for my target I need the "column_name" value.

```
public String updateColumnPreference(String column, String deveui, boolean pref) {
    int preference = (pref) ? 0 : 1;
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("preference", preference);
    db.update(ColumnsTableHelper.TABLE_C, values,
            ColumnsTableHelper.COLUMN_NAME + " = '" + column + "' AND " +
                    ColumnsTableHelper.COD_DEVEUI + " = '" + deveui + "'", null);
    db.close();
    return "Notifica mutata per " + column;
}
```

This is my update query in java.

Comment: Post your code and explain what you want to do.

Comment: Added my query code in java. As I wrote I want to update the column preference in a specific row

Comment: Your code is syntactically correct (although the way you update by concatenation is not recommended) and it updates the rows that meet the condition. Change to `int rows = update(....);` to get the number of the updated rows. If you are not satisfied with the result then maybe the rows in the table that meet the condition in the WHERE clause are different than you think.

Comment: Ok. I invite you to see my screenshots (the 3 links in the post), because is a little bit strange. If you watch the 2nd link there are my datas from table "Columns". As you can see cod_deveui is the foreign key so after n rows it changes. When I do a query in this table (3rd link) with a WHERE clause like column_name = "Numero1" the selection doesn't works and it works only when I select the first column_name value of each cod_deveui group. For example column_name = "Testo1" will return correctly 2 rows. Thank you and I hope that you can still suggest me something.

Comment: Execute this: `select column_name, length(column_name) from columns` and check for each value of `column_name` if it corresponds to the length of column_name that you see.

Comment: Ok, I've tried your query and I discovered that values contains some spaces so now I've fixed the problem. Thank you so much!